# Add maximize and source editing plugins for inline editing

Tags: ckeditor

when I use the inline editing stuff with the CKEditor, no maximize and source editing buttons are shown. How can I activate then for inline editing?

Thanks and Regards,

Ralf

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on Reinmar's answer so I'll just 'answer' instead. The fact that you can't see the need for this option doens't mean that it doesn't exist. I for one have a situation where I want to use the inline editor but will want to offer the option to maximize the editing area. I'll elaborate a bit.

In my case the (multiple) editing area(s) of fixed dimensions (=> scrolling div). These divs are used for users to enter data. In some cases though the divs aren't large enough for the users data and thus I would users to maximize the editing area. When they're done, they can close or restore the maximized editor and the data will be presented inside the scrolling div.

Basically what I want is having a page with multiple editing areas. The toolbar should only become visible when users start editing an area. The inline editor is ideal for this (even more if it could be shared for performance reasons) but it lacks the option to maximize.

Answer (score 1):

Inline source editing will be added in CKEditor 4.1 ([ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9713)). So in the middle of Feb it should be ready.

Maximize is impossible or rather senseless in inline editing. Inline editing is all about editing part of real pages. If you'll maximize editing area it won't be real. And it will be extremely hard to maximize it anyway, because that's an element on which we don't have full control.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Makes sense what you say. Since I work with the inline editing feature now I really like it and don't miss the maximization any more.

Comment: It's not impossible. Just give it `position:fixed` and correct dimentions and it will be maximized and even inherit all parent (if needed) styles. Next, pin the toolbar atop of it and control their dimention on window resize. Restore original position when user is done. Easy.
And btw, it makes sense in some cases.

Comment: As I wrote - it may not be so simple as you may think, although I'm not saying that it's impossible. I meant that it's impossible to achieve good result - believe me - when working with contenteditable everything is a pain. I also can't think of any interesting case when it makes sense to edit inline content in maximized container. If you know such, then you can create feature ticket on http://dev.ckeditor.com. We'll consider your case.

Answer (score 1):

I already made a plugin That includes the source editing in the inline mode here it is: [I can't add the Source button to CKEditor 4's toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617111/i-cant-add-the-source-button-to-ckeditor-4s-toolbar/14165997)

Comment: Thanks for the plugin hint. I added it to my project and it worked. Nice one. Though I will wait for the official inline source editing with CKEditor 4.1 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning source HTML: the inplace source editing is not available with the CK Editor 4 inline editor, but there is a solution:

- add the [Source Editing Area](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/sourcearea) plugin in your build of CKEditor
- modify the toolbar definition in your editorConfig to include the `Sourcedialog` item instead of the `Source` one:

  ```
  config.toolbar = [
      { name: 'document', items: ['Sourcedialog'] }, 
      ...
  ];
  ```